# Error en mi modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

buenos dias

El error esta cuando se carga la ventana se demora mucho en cargar y cuando secarga, carga muchas a la vez.

_show.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
           <center><h3 class="modal-title">SE CARGA MUCHAS VECES</h3></center>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
 <P>SE CARGA MUCHAS VECES

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>
     <%= link_to 'Editar', edit_centro_costo_path(@centro_costo),class:"btn btn-warning" %> 

</div>


</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

index.html.erb

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', centro_costo,remote: true %></td>
```

show.js.erb

```
$('<%= j render "show" %>').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
}).modal();
```

application.js

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require rails-ujs
 //= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
 //= require autocomplete-rails
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require bootstrap-sprockets
 //= require moment
 //= require moment/es
 //= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
 //= require toastr
 //= require pickers
 //= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss

```
   *= require toastr
   *= require jquery-ui
   *= require_tree .
   *= require_self
   */



@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";


.modal-dialog{
  overflow-y: initial !important
}
.modal-body-ejemplo{
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-header {

  background-color: #f08324;
  color: white;
 }
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu controlador? El que recibe la petición ajax.

Comment: @Gerry yo no modifico el controlador, lo raro es que tambie pasa en las ventanas modales de form pasa lo mismo.

Comment: no  recibe la petición por que yo no lo modifico